# Custom User Testing in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-custom-user

I have a Django application and the custom user - want to test it (do unit testing). My custom user is emailuser, which consists of e-mail and password fields. I want to set up something of such national mplayer, give it a field and a password. But my code below does not work.

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_user.EmailUser'
```

**My code in test.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.conf import settings

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.create('testuser@test.pl', 'testpass')

    def test_user(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user, 'testuser@test.pl')
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, try this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class CustomUserTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_create_user(self):
        # params = depends on your basemanager’s create_user methods.
        user = User.objects.create(**params)
        self.assertEqual(user.pk, user.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `create_user()` method instead of just `create()`. Also you should check the `email` field, not the `user` itself.

```
class MyTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.create_user(
                                              'testuser@test.pl', 'testpass')

    def test_user(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user.email, 'testuser@test.pl')
```